# How to give access rights in odoo v11?

Tags: odoo, odoo-11

I am getting the below `Odoo` Server Error - Access Error

> The requested operation cannot be completed due to security
>   restrictions. Please contact your system administrator.

(Document type: `hr.employee`, Operation: `read`)

Actually I created a rules for employees and manager
For manager:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="employee_view_rule_manager">
        <field name="name">Manager view rule</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="hr.model_hr_employee"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('hr.group_hr_manager'))]" />
        <field name="domain_force">[(1,'=',1)]</field>
    </record>
```

For Employees:

```
<record model="ir.rule" id="employee_view_rule_employee">
        <field name="name">Employee view rule</field>
        <field name="model_id" ref="hr.model_hr_employee"/>
        <field name="groups" eval="[(4, ref('base.group_user'))]" />

        <field name="perm_create" eval="False"/>

        <field name="domain_force">[('user_id', '=', user.id)]</field>
    </record>
```

It is working properly without installing `hr_org_char`t but when we install `hr_org_chart` app it gives read access error.

I need solution because we want organizational chart also.

Comment: Did you look into the rules or access rights of module/app hr_org_chart? Maybe you have new rules with it, which make your rules ineffective.

Comment: learn in the documentation of odoo, it have all the basic flows and functionalities or you need basic tutorials there are many websites to learn. For me i suggest http://glowodooerp.blogspot.com/

Answer (score 0):

i think you have issues of your domain

```
<field name="domain_force">[(1,'=',1)]</field>
```

if you apply this domain the employee can see own record only so you want child of employee list so you will use "child_of" try blow think it's will be work.

```
   <field name="domain_force">[('id', 'child_of', [user.id])]</field>
```

Thanks